# ggplot2: how to combine layers of geom_line and geom_point with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I'm trying to generate a line graph of four data conditions, plotting the average of each condition as a function of time. The conditions vary in a 2x2 design, so I've been using geom_line (blue/red lines that are solid/dashed) and geom_point (blue/red shapes that are squares/circles) to plot the data. That works just fine when I use layers, but I'd also like to include error bars at each time point:

```
pd <- position_dodge(.1)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, condition == "A"), aes(E, avg),
        colour="red", size=1) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, condition == "A"), aes(E, avg), 
         colour="red", shape=24, fill="white", size=5) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, condition == "B"), aes(E, avg),
        colour="red", linetype="dashed",size=1) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, condition == "B"), aes(E, avg), 
         colour="red", shape=24, fill="red", size=5) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, condition == "C"), aes(E, avg),
        colour="blue", size=1) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, condition == "C"), aes(E, avg), 
         colour="blue", shape=21, fill="white", size=5) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, condition == "D"), aes(E, avg),
        colour="blue", linetype="dashed",size=1) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, condition == "D"), aes(E, avg), 
         colour="blue", shape=21, fill="blue", size=5)
```

The above code works fine. But if I then add in this line:

```
+ geom_errorbar(aes(x=E, ymin=avg-se, ymax=avg+se), width=.1, position=pd)
```

The plot does not take pd (which has been defined previously) into account, and the bars are hard to distinguish from one another (i.e., overlapping). How do I remedy this?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: You do not define `x` in your `aes` call.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't the code that I pasted define x in the aes call as y=min=avg-se, ymax=avg+se ?

Comment: it looks like you want something like `aes(x=E, ymin=avg-se, ymax=avg+se)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That code adds in the error bars, but overrides the arguments that separate out the error bars a bit in order to distinguish them. Is there a way to add that back in?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, as I was trying to articulate my question in a concise manner. Obviously, I should have mentioned that earlier code that I didn't paste in this question defined pd, which I have now edited to include in the question. Thus, even though pd is defined earlier, your suggested code doesn't seem to take pd into account, and the bars overlap. If you have suggestions for how to remedy this, I'd be grateful, and am also appreciative of your help thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely rewrote your code using `aes` the way it is supposed to be used together with manual scales.

```
# sample data 
df <- data.frame(condition = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5), 
                 E = rep(1:5, times = 4), 
                 avg = rnorm(20), 
                 se = .3)
# plotting command
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = E, 
                      y = avg, 
                      color = condition, 
                      linetype = condition, 
                      shape = condition, 
                      fill = condition)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + 
  geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(A = "red", B = "red", C = "blue", D = "blue"), 
                     guide = "none") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(A = "solid", B = "dashed", C = "solid", D = "dashed"), 
                        guide = "none") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(A = 24, B = 24, C = 21, D = 21), 
                     guide = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "white", B = "red", C = "white", D = "blue"), 
                    guide = "none") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = E, ymin = avg-se, ymax = avg+se, color = NULL, linetype = NULL), 
                width=.1, position=position_dodge(width = .1))
```